# FlatMap a Flux not executed

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a list which contains 240 items, this list takes over 1 hour to be completely sent using `for`.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> conventions = mapConventions(objects, referentialService);

for(Map<String, Object> item : conventions) {
        webClient.post()
        .uri(configProperties.getUrl().getConvention() + CONVENTION)
        .bodyValue(objectMapper.convertValue(item, JsonNode.class))
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class);
}
```

So I followed this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-simultaneous-calls#1-multiple-calls-to-the-same-service) to send it simultaneously to minimize the response time, but the code inside the `flatmap` is never executed:

```
Flux.fromIterable(conventions).flatMap(item ->  {
    System.out.print(item);
    return webClient.post()
            .uri(configProperties.getUrl().getConvention() + CONVENTION)
            .bodyValue(objectMapper.convertValue(item, JsonNode.class))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
});
```

Comment: And conventions is? Please provide a more complete code example. The only reason flatmap is not executed is if conventions is empty.

Comment: in the first snippet, aren't you missing a `block()` or `.subscribe()` or something similar? this code basically creates multiple `Mono` in a loop, but none of the Monos seem to be subscribed/used nor returned... I wonder how it can process anything.

Answer (score 2):

In Reactive programming, there are Producers and Subscribers. While a Producer can output results, it doesn't do any good if nothing is listening to those results -- that is where the Subscriber comes into play. A Subscriber handles the output of the Producer and does something meaningful with the result.  The is so fundamental to Reactive Programming that a Producer will not execute any code if a Subscriber isn't "listening" for the results.

So in this case the `flatmap()` is the Producer. And it will not execute any code unless there is a Subscriber to handle the output.

The short answer is to add a `subscribe()` call at the end of the flatmap. To Look something like this.

```
Flux.fromIterable(conventions).flatMap(item ->  {
    System.out.print(item);
    return webClient.post()
            .uri(configProperties.getUrl().getConvention() + CONVENTION)
            .bodyValue(objectMapper.convertValue(item, JsonNode.class))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
}).subscribe();
```

Many tutorials have been written about this.
for Example:
https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/13/notes-on-reactive-programming-part-ii-writing-some-code
https://medium.com/@olehdokuka/mastering-own-reactive-streams-implementation-part-1-publisher-e8eaf928a78c
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/

Comment: if the code above should add a subscribe or not is all about the context around the code. That is why i asked for more context around the code. This answer provides a solution to the problem, but it might not be the answer the his problem.

Comment: Given your insight, I have adjusted the answer to give more context as to why the code is needed.  I would appreciate it if you could re-evaluate.